# How to modify the <head> of a lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, mobile, aura

I'm currently working on a Lightning app that needs to be rendered on mobile but I'm unable to add the `meta` tag to the `head`

I've tried with

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>');
```

and with

```
$('head').append("<meta name=viewport content=width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0/>");
```

Both are not working, the only difference is that without jQuery I get an

```
Uncaught Error: Access denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is for a standalone app, you can do it directly in the vf page then include the component with ltng:out

Sample :

```
 <html style="height: 100% !important;">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" id="viewPortCloudIRMvfCmpLightningIncluder"/>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="lightningvfDIV4CRM" style="min-height: 100vh !important;height: 100vh;display:none;"/>

        <script>

            $Lightning.use("c:MyApp4vf", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:MyCmp", // Component name
                                           {  },
                                           "lightningvfDIV4CRM",
                                           function(cmp) {

                                           });
            });           
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

But i agree there should be a standard way to do that, dear SalesForce could u provide some force global event to call to put viewport header ? :)

Comment: And if two different components want to set this to different values who would win? Whichever component was loaded last? Lightning is designed to let code written by different vendors co-exist on the same page.

Comment: I started my answer by "if it is a standalone app". If it is for components included in the CRM view of SalesForce in the middle of other components , i don't think that adding viewport header has sense